# concatenar arquivos em c#

Tags: c#

Bom dia

tenho vários arquivos txt em um mesmo diretório marcos-1,marcos-2...,
só que preciso criar um arquivo só. mas com um agravante que cada arquivo será uma coluna do arquivo final. como se fosse uma matriz. onde cada arquivo é coluna da matriz.

Alguém poderia me socorrer

Comment: É preciso dar mais informações para podermos tentar responder. De qualquer forma, fez alguma coisa? Está com algum problema específico?

Answer (score 2):

A maneira performática é assim:

```
const int chunkSize = 2 * 1024; // 2KB
var inputFiles = new[] { "marcos1.txt", "marcos2.txt", "marcos3.txt" };
using (var output = File.Create("marcos-juntos.txt"))
{
    foreach (var file in inputFiles)
    {
        using (var input = File.OpenRead(file))
        {
            var buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Tirei daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6311392/1314276).